# How to show a preview thumbnail on Facebook of a imageless website?

Tags: css, facebook, images, detection, thumbnail

I have recently designed a website with no img tags, only one big fat CSS sprite with everything in it. Though, when I try to publish that website on Facebook, it won't show a preview thumbnail — probably because it doesn't find any images on the markup. Any suggestions? I'd still like to keep it a super fast img-less website, nevertheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest this reading

> [How to Get Your Website Preview Thumbnail to Show Up on Facebook Share](http://www.ehow.com/how_4938148_thumbnail-show-up-facebook-share.html)

[Google](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=facebook+link+thumbnail) is your friend :)

---

It all resumes to add a meta info to your code as:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://site.com/website-thumb.jpg" />
```

and try not to make that image more than 250px wide.

Comment: Indeed it is. :)

Answer (score 3):

Facebook uses a proprietary link type called `image_src`:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="location/of/image" />
```

Just insert that in your `<head>` and Facebook should be able to pick up on the image.

If you're also interested, Facebook also recognizes two other `rel` values: `audio_src` and `video_src`. [See here for more](http://www.niallkennedy.com/blog/2009/03/enhanced-social-share.html).

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `<html>` tag with `<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">`

Add the given meta tag inside your head tag.

```
 <head>
    <meta property="og:title" content="TITLE TO BE DISPLAYED"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="IMAGE URL"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="DESCRIPTION"/>  
    </head>
```

Title and description are optional in your case. This will work for sites utilizing open graph protocol.